# Utility in framework for defining SVG path strings more easily?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying out the svg capabilities via the Raphael framework (it's path docs are [here](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path)).  I find writing the path string to be very tedious because I have to constantly look up the format specs when either creating a new path or looking at one already written.  Is there a framework that simplifies this process?  For example, instead of having to write something like:

```
function pathStringForBoxWithQuad(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var edgeLength = 8;
    var str = "M " + (x2 + edgeLength) + " " + y1; // move to top right
    str += " L " + x1 + " " + y1; // line to top left
    str += " L " + x1 + " " + y2; // line to bottom left
    str += " L " + (x2 + edgeLength) + " " + y2; // line to bottom right
    str += " Q " + x2 + " " + (y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2) + " " + (x2 + edgeLength) + " " + y1; // quadratic back to top right
    str += " Z";
    return str;
}
```

you could write something like the following, but it would give the same string back:

```
function pathStringForBoxWithQuad(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var edgeLength = 8;
    var str = new SVGPathString()
            .moveTo(x2 + edgeLength, y1)
            .lineTo(x1, y1)
            .lineTo(x1, y2)
            .lineTo(x2 + edgeLength, y2)
            .quadTo(x2, (y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2), x2 + edgeLength, y1 );
    return str;
}
```

Does anything like the second method exist in popular frameworks?  I find this type of path construction alot more reader friendly.

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for something similar but for now I ended up using Underscore.js to create templates for SVG commands. something like..

```
var commands = {
    line: _.template('M<%= x1 %>,<%= y1 %> L<%= x2 %>,<%= y2 %>'),
  .....
}
....
commands.line({
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,

    x2: 0,
    y2: 10        
})
```

Comment: This is an interesting diy approach.  A bit more verbose than the one I suggested, but certainly more informative than the currently provided path syntax.

Answer (score 1):

What you want looks a bit similar to the [SVGPath API](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/svgudom.html#svg__SVGPath) in SVG Tiny 1.2, sans the stringification. These path objects are not meant to waste time on serialization, they're meant to be assigned directly. Of all the current browsers, the SVGPath API is only implemented by Opera AFAIK.

The SVG WG is looking at improving the path API for SVG2 though, so hopefully there will be something better in the future.

Comment: It's good to know they are still working on it, thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

There's always the SVG DOM.

```
  var path = document.getElementById("<pathId>");
  var segments = path.pathSegList;
```

When you need to create new path segments, you need to use methods like

```
var newSegment = path.createSVGPathSegArcAbs(...)
```

call segments.appendItem or segments.insertItemBefore to add it. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-SVG11-20030114/paths.html#DOMInterfaces for more details.